# Can we consider that ethernet or RS-232 (RS-485) networks have no ground connection between the two ends of each cable?

Tags: ground, network-interface, ground-loop

This is for a huge home theater.

I have a power transformer that converts 380VAC between two legs of a 3-phase power system down to 230VAC, with a center-tap of the secondary being our "neutral" for this secondary. (FYI, there are three such transformers, connected between phases A and B; B and C; and C and A. All this is needed.)

A hundred feet away we have a Lutron lighting panel that operates at 230 VAC from one leg of the same 3-phase power, on the same breaker panel, to neutral.

The lighting system is controlled via a Crestron system powered at the above-mentioned transformer, with control from the Crestron to the Lutron via RS-485.

If the RS-485 cabling makes a connection from the chassis ground of the Crestron system to the chassis ground of the Lutron, it looks like we have a HUGE ground loop. Hence the question, which I'd like to generalize:

Do ethernet, RS-232, and/or RS-485 essentially isolate grounds at the two ends of their cables?  Do they carry a ground through?  Does it depend on the equipment?

Comment: All of your chassis grounds need to be at roughly the same potential. Otherwise, you've got bigger problems than a ground loop through a comm cable. Problems like electrocuting someone who touches both chassis at the same time. BTW, they should be connected to the same building earthing system anyway.

Comment: Thank you!  However, in audio equipment, a one volt potential difference can cause audible hum.  Do you happen to have a direct answer to my question?

Answer (score 2):

Ethernet uses galvanic isolation with transformer coupling at both ends of the link.  RS-232 and RS-485 do not.  You have to use line coding in order to use AC coupling through either transformers or capacitors.  This is part of the Ethernet spec.  However, no low speed protocol supports this.  However, it should be possible to get a box that can provide isolation for RS-232 or RS-485.

Comment: Thanks for the start here, but I'm not getting it... maybe. I don't know if my Crestron programmer uses "line coding," so that part doesn't help. I think you are saying that the ground of a chassis with an RS-232 output is connected via the RS-232 cable to the ground at the chassis at the other end of the cable unless I use line coding... whatever that is... and tell me, if I use line coding, do I HAVE to use AC coupling? That is, without using line coding I cannot have isolation; with line coding is isolation possible or necessary? Thanks!  Hey, this edit window doesn't let me use paragraphs!

Comment: Basically, Ethernet uses a line code to remove the DC component so the signal will pass through transformers.  RS-232 and RS-485 do not support this, so you will need to use an active isolator of some sort.  Basically, you can get boxes with a pair of RS-232 connectors that have optoisolators (or similar) inside to provide galvanic isolation.

Comment: For example: http://www.usconverters.com/rs232-isolator